# Correct implementation of Min-Max in a tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, minmax

I implemented the min-max algorithm on a tree. The algorithm I created is working as intented, returning the path in the tree that corresponds to the min and max values. But my problem is that it doesn't feel right. 
My question is , is that a correct implementation of the min-max algorithm?

I couldn't find a pure implementation of the algorithm in a tree structure that consists of nodes. On the examples I manages to find ,people implemented the algorithm to solve problems related to games (tic-tac-toe). To be honest I felt stupid I couldn't make the connection.
 
I used 2 functions ,
1->evaluations_function which traverses the tree and adds value to nodes that don't have (a.k.a. all nodes that are not leaves). 
2->print_optimal which traverses the tree and returns the path .

```
public void evaluation_function(Node root, int maxHeight, int rootHeight) {
        if (root.childrenList.Count != 0) {
            foreach (Node node in root.childrenList) {
                evaluation_function(node, maxHeight, rootHeight);
            }
        }
        if (root.height != rootHeight) {
            if ((root.height % 2) == 0) {
                if (root.value < root.parent.value || root.parent.value == 123456) {
                    root.parent.value = root.value;
                }
            } else if ((root.height % 2) != 0) {
                if (root.value > root.parent.value || root.parent.value == 123456) {
                    root.parent.value = root.value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is print_optimal

```
public void print_optimal(Node root) {
        int maxValue = 0;
        int minValue = 9999;
        if (root.childrenList.Count != 0) {
            if (root.height % 2 == 0) {
                foreach (Node child in root.childrenList) {
                    if (child.value > maxValue) { maxValue = child.value; }
                }
                foreach (Node child in root.childrenList) {
                    if (child.value == maxValue) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Selected node " + child.name
                            + " with value = " + child.value + " as MAX player");
                        print_optimal(child);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                foreach (Node child in root.childrenList) {
                    if (child.value < minValue) { minValue = child.value; }
                }
                foreach (Node child in root.childrenList) {
                    if (child.value == minValue) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Selected node " + child.name
                            + " with value = " + child.value + " as MIN player");
                        print_optimal(child);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't want to swarm the question with code , as my question is theoretical. But if you want to see the data struct or want to test the algorithm you can find it here : https://github.com/AcidDreamer/AI_Exercises/tree/master/1.2.1/Exercise1_2_1/Exercise1_2_1  
 

IMPROVEMENT
evaluation_function changed to

```
public void evaluation_function(Node root, int rootHeight) {
        if (root.childrenList.Count != 0) {
            foreach (Node node in root.childrenList) {
                evaluation_function(node, rootHeight);
            }
        }
        if (root.height != rootHeight || root.childrenList.Count != 0) {
            int maxValue = 0, minValue = 999;
            if ((root.height % 2) == 0) {
                foreach (Node child in root.childrenList) {
                    if (maxValue < child.value) {
                        maxValue = child.value;
                        root.value = maxValue;
                        root.bestChild = child;
                    }
                }
            } else if ((root.height % 2) != 0) {
                foreach (Node child in root.childrenList) {
                    if (minValue > child.value) {
                        minValue = child.value;
                        root.value = minValue;
                        root.bestChild = child;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

giving values to the current nodes.
print_optimal had a huge improvement using a bestChild field and is changed to

```
public void print_optimal(Node root) {
        if (root.bestChild != null) {
            Console.Write(root.name + "->");
            print_optimal(root.bestChild);
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine(root.name);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it a little unnatural that the `evaluation_function`, which receives a Node as input, actually updates the value for the parent node.

I feel that a better approach would be for that function to update the current node instead.

It should do nothing if the current node is a leaf.

Otherwise, it should iterate through all the children (as it currently does in the first loop), and after each recursive call for a child, it should also check whether the current node value should be updated (*i.e.* a better value was just encountered, for the current child).

In addition, it is possible to add an additional field to each node, *e.g.* `bestChild`, or `bestMove`, to avoid re-iterating through children when calling `print-optimal`.

Comment: the bestChild you suggested is indeed an amazing and thought and thanks for mentioning . I'll work on your suggestions  and see what I can make of it , I'll update once I'm done ,thanks for your time!

Comment: you're welcome, looking forward to hearing back from you!

Comment: As expected bestChild is an amazing quality of life addition . Updated the question.
The code is more understandable and much more clean , thanks a lot for the suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Overall your code is good (which you knew, since it works), but I have some remarks about improvements:

**evaluation_function**: you do not use `maxHeight` at all. Use it or remove the parameter. It's weird (kind of bad practice) that the function changes the parents of the current node. It should rather look at the children's values (if not leaf), and update the current node's value depending on that. Besides, you could add a field to keep track of the best child (or even of the selected path to a leaf) to avoid the matching process in `print`_optimal.

**print_optimal()**: You currently have a problem if 2 children have the same values: you'll print both of them and explore both trees. Checking `if (child.value < minValue) { minValue = child.value; }` is useless since you assume you've already used `evaluation_function()`, and it is not enough to "replace" `evaluation_function` if you had forgotten to do so.

Comment: I removed the maxHeight ( forgot to remove it after some testing ) , both yours and @quertyman 's responses are similar , so I'll work on swapping the current nodes value. I'll use a bestChild field to help me explore the tree , and thanks for the time you took replying!

Comment: For a first go you should definetly remove maxHeight. If in the future you want to work on big games and have a more broadly-usable algorithm, you'll need maxHeight again when you can't afford to  (or just can't) explore the tree completely to the leaves

Comment: Hopefully in the future I'll be able to use the logic in much broader problems . Updated the question.

Comment: The code is much better now, congrats ! However, now rootHeight is not really useful any more, you could remove it.